# Размещение меток на данной карте

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Помогите, пожалуйста, разместить метки на данной карте http://oasis.coal.tilda.ws/city, вот скрипт подключения карты https://oasisoasisoasis.github.io/map/map.js . Совсем ничего не выходит

Comment: А что не получается? Вот тут есть много разнообразных примеров: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1

Comment: Не получается разместить метки, делал по примерам, они просто не появляются

Comment: Почините все 404 ошибки которые у вас появляются в консоли http://oasis.coal.tilda.ws/city и метки появятся.

Comment: Вроде как нет никаких ошибок

Comment: Ясно, у меня есть. Видимо вы пользуетесь не хромом. Можно воспользоваться chrome или посмотрите во вкладке сеть в инструментах разработчика, какие ресурсы не могут загрузиться, так как сервер отвечает 404 на них.